# Database Schema for categorized tags

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am trying to set up my database to have a somewhat complex form of filtering. It will end up looking similar to Amazon filters on the side, handful of categories with many tags in each category.

I have quite a few tables in postgres to manage my elements.

Every item belongs to a project so I have a main item table which stores a foreign key to a projects table as well as a few identifying tags.

Then every project belongs to a company so the projects table stores a foreign key to a companies table as well as more identifying tags.

And finally the companies table is the root table. It must store information about which categories of tags a company chooses to include in their workspace. (example, do they want to tag their items by color, make, model? Or maybe they want color and age range only? etc)

When the items are presented to the user, they are filterable based on that items tags, the projects tags that that item belongs too, but only the tag categories the company chose to include.

At first, I was trying to just add columns to my table for each tag category with a check constraint on the columns to limit it to specific tags. Projects had extra tag category columns and so did details and then the two tables get joined to be able to filter based on any of the tags.

I have not been able to figure out how to make the companies have different sets of categories yet. I was thinking maybe I just keep adding columns to the tables and then just set up the UI so that specific companies can only see and access the columns they have chosen to include but that doesn't seem scalable.

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is a many-to-many (M:M) between tables `Companies` and `Tags`.  The solution is to create another table `Company-Tags` containing FK to `Compaines` and `Tags`  and any additional columns that are specific to that combination, if any.

```
create table company_tags(
             cmpy_id    integer   
                        references companies(cmpy_id) 
           , tag_id     integer 
                        references tags(tag_id) 
           , constraint company_tag_id 
                        primary key(cmpy_id, tag_id)
           );
```

That gives you the specific tags a company has selected and what companies have selected specific tags.